# How do I fix a nil error when trying to save an image to library?

Tags: swift, xcode, error-handling

I'm building an app that takes a picture and then you will have the option to save it. However before you have taken a picture the UIImageView is empty (nil) and when you press the save button it crashes because you can't save photos that are nil. How can I make an error handling so it doesn't crash when the UIImageView is nil.

I've tried throw and catch but can't get it to work.

```
func tryDataConversion() throws -> Data {
        let imageData = myImage.image!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)
        return imageData!
    }
```

Full code for action func that I want to work:

```
@IBAction func saveImageButton(_ sender: Any) {
            let imageData = myImage.image!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)
            let compressedImage = UIImage(data: imageData!)
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(compressedImage!, nil, nil, nil)

            alert(title: "Recent Photo Saved", msg: "Your most recent photo has been saved to your photo library")
    }
```

as soon as the following line it crashes because when unwrapping it founds nil and it can unwrap nil.

```
let imageData = myImage.image!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)
```

and gives the following error.

```
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value:
```

Comment: Don't force-unwrap optionals. But why not figure out why the image view's `image` property isn't set?

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
let imageData = myImage.image!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)
let compressedImage = UIImage(data: imageData!)
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(compressedImage!, nil, nil, nil)
```

try this:

```
if let imageData = myImage.image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0), 
let compressedImage = UIImage(data: imageData) {
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(compressedImage!, nil, nil, nil)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to throw an error to handle you need to create an error:

```
enum DataConversionError: Error {
  case emptyImage
}

func tryDataConversion() throws -> Data {
  guard let imageData = someData else {
      throw DataConversionError.emptyImage
  }

  return imageData
}

func handleSaveButtonTap() {
  do {
      let imageData = try tryDataConversion()
      // Do something with your imageData
      print(imageData)
  }
  catch {
      // Handle your error here
      print("UIImageView is empty")
      print("Error: \(error)")
      return
  }
}
```